# Can I restrict SQL Server to execute code only when some code is selected?

Tags: sql-server, database, azure-sql-database

The other day I was trying to hit another button on the menu but hit Execute - which executed the whole code and ended up deleting some tables. I have always found this scary that hitting one button can execute the whole code.

I want SQL Server to execute code only when something is selected. Is it possible? Or can SQL Server prompt before executing a query?

Comment: Depends on what your running the sql in/from.  If I have a scratch-pad type query in ssms I always make sure the first line is `return`.

Answer (score 6):

If you wrap your code in `NOEXEC` then you [effectively stop the code from running](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-noexec-transact-sql) unless you select the code inside them.
The code will compile but will not execute!

Example:

```
SET NOEXEC ON;

SELECT 1 AS Test;

SET NOEXEC OFF;
```

If you run the whole code, nothing will be returned.

If you highlight just the `SELECT` part then it will run though, returning:

```
Test
----
1
```

Comment: Nice idea!  You could edit the new query template (`SQLFile.sql` -> located ...\Microsoft SQL Server\<version>\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\SqlWorkbenchProjectItems\) to automatically include this.

Comment: Good point! I think I read somewhere that someone does that for `BEGIN TRAN` and `ROLLBACK`...

Answer (score 1):

In MSSQL Management Studio, the Execute button (F5) executes only the sentences that are selected. If nothing is selected, then executes the complete script.

I allways select the sentences I want to execute. But it's my habit. Nothing will prevent you from pressing F5 directly